# Magento Error in backend

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

We have a fatal error in our admin panel and the strange thing is that we can not say when. It just shows up once in a while. The error is:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:99:"Missing locale file '/home/ilfnshop/public_html/lib/Zend/Locale/Data/nl_NL.xml' for 'nl_NL' locale.";i:1;s:4018:"#0 /home/modemust/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Date.php(1091): Zend_Date->_calculate('set', '2013-08-19 22:0...', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:0...', 'nl_NL')
#1 /home/modemust/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Date.php(210): Zend_Date->set('2013-08-19 22:0...', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:0...', 'nl_NL')
#2 /home/modemust/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Graph.php(386): Zend_Date->__construct('2013-08-19 22:0...', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:0...')
#3 /home/modemust/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/dashboard/graph.phtml(61): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Graph->getChartUrl(false)
#4 /home/modemust/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/modemust/...')
#5 /home/modemust/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
```

I could not yet find anything like this. Hopefully someone can help me with the issue?

Answer (score 0):

1) try to reproduce steps to get the error, this will give more clues to the root of the cause

2) it looks like something to do with the dashboard sales graph (date, graph files mentioned)

These are CORE files (except #3), which means they should never have been edited by either yourself or a third-party. If all else failes I would backup your site then re-download the same version of Magento and replace the files which are affected.